# Issue with Dancer2 dependency when building snapcast-volume-ui with Nix

Tags: perl, packaging, nix, nixos

I'm attempted to build a nix container for [snapcast-volume-ui](https://github.com/atoomic/snapcast-volume-ui). I have the following `snapcast-volume-ui.nix` file:

```
{ pkgs, fetchurl, ... }:
let
snapcast-volume-ui-config = pkgs.writeTextFile {
    name = "snapcast-volume-ui-config";
    destination = "/etc/dancer2-config.yml";
    text = ''
    appname: "snapdance"
    layout: "main"
    template: "template_toolkit"
    engines:
      template:
        template_toolkit:
          start_tag: '<%'
          end_tag:   '%>'
    snapcast:
      demo: 0
      server:
         host: 'localhost'
         port: 1705
      rooms:
        'ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee':
           color: '#0C0'
           name:  'Mezzanine'
    '';
};

Dancer2 = pkgs.perlPackages.buildPerlPackage rec {
  pname = "Dancer2";
  version = "0.400000";
  src = fetchurl {
    url = "mirror://cpan/authors/id/F/FL/FLORA/${pname}-${version}.tar.gz";
    sha256 = "1bl8z095y4js66pwxnm7s853pi9czala4sqc743fdlnk27kq94gz";
  };
};

snapcast-volume-ui-src = fetchGit {
  url = "https://github.com/atoomic/snapcast-volume-ui.git";
  ref = "snapcast/v0.12";
  rev = "5eb4076607aab7e69b08a96b902029bd1091c056";
};

snapcast-volume-ui = pkgs.perlPackages.buildPerlPackage rec {
  pname = "snapcast-volume-ui";
  version = "0.21";
  src = snapcast-volume-ui-src;
  propagatedBuildInputs = [Dancer2];
};

in
pkgs.dockerTools.buildLayeredImage {
  name = "snapcast-volume-ui";
  contents = [ pkgs.busybox snapcast-volume-ui snapcast-volume-ui-config ];
  config = {
    # Entrypoint = [ "" ];
    Entrypoint = [ "sleep" "1d" ];
    Env = [];
    Volumes = {};
  };
}
```

Even when Dancer2 successfully builds, I still get the following error output when it attempts to build the snapcast-volume-ui:

```
2023-01-12 11:54:11,372 ERROR: building '/nix/store/hyz5003jklskkhkqdpfr6nc04zbh7782-snapcast-volume-ui-config.drv'...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,372 ERROR: copying path '/nix/store/jrd33ilrl76ani5z8n0wp6dqin27px89-curl-7.86.0-man' from 'https://cache.nixos.org'...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,372 ERROR: copying path '/nix/store/7cwhxwp5ljl7rrwn7whxapgv075xvcxq-libkrb5-1.20' from 'https://cache.nixos.org'...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,372 ERROR: copying path '/nix/store/844bjdxlcm03cyx4psdgiyxp94j86sa8-mirrors-list' from 'https://cache.nixos.org'...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,372 ERROR: copying path '/nix/store/i9g4aqgrywxaq5yd9d3111y6qqf1p2m6-libkrb5-1.20-dev' from 'https://cache.nixos.org'...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,372 ERROR: copying path '/nix/store/djlpdhbczmcvb6lyqrzhrhvvp2zl8gyl-nghttp2-1.49.0' from 'https://cache.nixos.org'...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,372 ERROR: copying path '/nix/store/1p2pxij9c1gxb05il19p663n26yi7x6j-nghttp2-1.49.0-bin' from 'https://cache.nixos.org'...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,372 ERROR: copying path '/nix/store/28yxnrka6j5hilmcddx1yyginva7ff2b-nghttp2-1.49.0-lib' from 'https://cache.nixos.org'...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,372 ERROR: copying path '/nix/store/8anr41ba72dqji5l37sdpwgak1qhf8ir-openssl-3.0.7' from 'https://cache.nixos.org'...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,372 ERROR: copying path '/nix/store/48fswm817f3llafj8ccan4pdvk7sv8ln-nghttp2-1.49.0-dev' from 'https://cache.nixos.org'...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,373 ERROR: copying path '/nix/store/x68d6j1qw27xxks2p5wm7l5scsin8zfa-libssh2-1.10.0' from 'https://cache.nixos.org'...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,373 ERROR: copying path '/nix/store/2w27qrbrxmimslpn2rx4mvq8n9q7sckc-openssl-3.0.7-bin' from 'https://cache.nixos.org'...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,373 ERROR: copying path '/nix/store/r94cmzg4ay80mqbj6g768n332405m6a9-curl-7.86.0' from 'https://cache.nixos.org'...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,373 ERROR: copying path '/nix/store/4nxpd816ypsz7brncrzixiy4mg5ksl0l-libssh2-1.10.0-dev' from 'https://cache.nixos.org'...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,373 ERROR: copying path '/nix/store/757ni9bhhgxnkl2ry922w62bk59mc94n-curl-7.86.0-bin' from 'https://cache.nixos.org'...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,373 ERROR: copying path '/nix/store/9v945ncgzqagpj1dhqzn550x87nj0f43-openssl-3.0.7-dev' from 'https://cache.nixos.org'...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,373 ERROR: copying path '/nix/store/s0fl4ff6p93p5hs454147jpqmym74x2h-curl-7.86.0-dev' from 'https://cache.nixos.org'...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,373 ERROR: building '/nix/store/afnvlikycvf0qvdyqgjrh3jxqbm42v8x-Dancer2-0.400000.tar.gz.drv'...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,373 ERROR: 
2023-01-12 11:54:11,373 ERROR: trying https://tarballs.nixos.org/sha256/1bl8z095y4js66pwxnm7s853pi9czala4sqc743fdlnk27kq94gz
2023-01-12 11:54:11,373 ERROR:   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
2023-01-12 11:54:11,373 ERROR:                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
2023-01-12 11:54:11,373 ERROR:   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
2023-01-12 11:54:11,373 ERROR: 100 31240  100 31240    0     0   222k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  222k
2023-01-12 11:54:11,373 ERROR: building '/nix/store/4k2lls08sz0s3413cqrh74jyrkr8wjjk-perl5.36.0-Dancer2-0.400000.drv'...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,373 ERROR: unpacking sources
2023-01-12 11:54:11,373 ERROR: unpacking source archive /nix/store/bd054ssl71bir70rvkmfs0dqbf8pdmn4-Dancer2-0.400000.tar.gz
2023-01-12 11:54:11,373 ERROR: source root is Class-C3-0.21
2023-01-12 11:54:11,373 ERROR: setting SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH to timestamp 1237940534 of file Class-C3-0.21/inc/Module/Install/WriteAll.pm
2023-01-12 11:54:11,373 ERROR: patching sources
2023-01-12 11:54:11,373 ERROR: configuring
2023-01-12 11:54:11,373 ERROR: patching ./util/visualize_c3.pl...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,373 ERROR: patching ./t/05_MRO.t...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,373 ERROR: patching ./t/34_next_method_in_eval.t...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,373 ERROR: patching ./t/10_Inconsistent_hierarchy.t...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,373 ERROR: patching ./t/24_more_overload.t...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,373 ERROR: patching ./t/36_next_goto.t...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,373 ERROR: patching ./t/pod.t...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,373 ERROR: patching ./t/30_next_method.t...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,373 ERROR: patching ./t/02_MRO.t...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,373 ERROR: patching ./t/20_reinitialize.t...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,373 ERROR: patching ./t/00_load.t...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,373 ERROR: patching ./t/32_next_method_edge_cases.t...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,373 ERROR: patching ./t/31_next_method_skip.t...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,373 ERROR: patching ./t/03_MRO.t...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,373 ERROR: patching ./t/04_MRO.t...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,373 ERROR: patching ./t/21_C3_with_overload.t...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,373 ERROR: patching ./t/22_uninitialize.t...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,373 ERROR: patching ./t/23_multi_init.t...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,373 ERROR: patching ./t/33_next_method_used_with_NEXT.t...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,373 ERROR: patching ./t/01_MRO.t...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,373 ERROR: patching ./t/35_next_method_in_anon.t...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,374 ERROR: patching ./t/06_MRO.t...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,374 ERROR: patching ./t/pod_coverage.t...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,374 ERROR: Cannot determine perl version info from lib/Class/C3.pm
2023-01-12 11:54:11,374 ERROR: Checking if your kit is complete...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,374 ERROR: Looks good
2023-01-12 11:54:11,374 ERROR: Generating a Unix-style Makefile
2023-01-12 11:54:11,374 ERROR: Writing Makefile for Class::C3
2023-01-12 11:54:11,374 ERROR: Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
2023-01-12 11:54:11,374 ERROR: no configure script, doing nothing
2023-01-12 11:54:11,374 ERROR: building
2023-01-12 11:54:11,374 ERROR: build flags: SHELL=/nix/store/wim4mqpn8lxhhr10p2kd070hyj152lil-bash-5.1-p16/bin/bash
2023-01-12 11:54:11,374 ERROR: cp lib/Class/C3.pm blib/lib/Class/C3.pm
2023-01-12 11:54:11,374 ERROR: cp lib/Class/C3/next.pm blib/lib/Class/C3/next.pm
2023-01-12 11:54:11,374 ERROR: Manifying 2 pod documents
2023-01-12 11:54:11,374 ERROR: running tests
2023-01-12 11:54:11,374 ERROR: check flags: SHELL=/nix/store/wim4mqpn8lxhhr10p2kd070hyj152lil-bash-5.1-p16/bin/bash VERBOSE=y test
2023-01-12 11:54:11,374 ERROR: PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/nix/store/ir8rqkxsqh0ar3avlvhs2crn0zx2d2mk-perl-5.36.0/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'inc', 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
2023-01-12 11:54:11,374 ERROR: t/00_load.t ........................ ok   
2023-01-12 11:54:11,374 ERROR: t/01_MRO.t ......................... ok     
2023-01-12 11:54:11,374 ERROR: t/02_MRO.t ......................... ok     
2023-01-12 11:54:11,374 ERROR: t/03_MRO.t ......................... ok   
2023-01-12 11:54:11,374 ERROR: t/04_MRO.t ......................... ok   
2023-01-12 11:54:11,374 ERROR: t/05_MRO.t ......................... ok   
2023-01-12 11:54:11,374 ERROR: t/06_MRO.t ......................... ok   
2023-01-12 11:54:11,374 ERROR: t/10_Inconsistent_hierarchy.t ...... ok   
2023-01-12 11:54:11,374 ERROR: t/20_reinitialize.t ................ ok   
2023-01-12 11:54:11,374 ERROR: t/21_C3_with_overload.t ............ ok   
2023-01-12 11:54:11,374 ERROR: t/22_uninitialize.t ................ ok     
2023-01-12 11:54:11,374 ERROR: t/23_multi_init.t .................. ok   
2023-01-12 11:54:11,374 ERROR: t/24_more_overload.t ............... ok   
2023-01-12 11:54:11,374 ERROR: t/30_next_method.t ................. ok   
2023-01-12 11:54:11,374 ERROR: t/31_next_method_skip.t ............ ok     
2023-01-12 11:54:11,374 ERROR: t/32_next_method_edge_cases.t ...... ok     
2023-01-12 11:54:11,374 ERROR: t/33_next_method_used_with_NEXT.t .. ok   
2023-01-12 11:54:11,374 ERROR: t/34_next_method_in_eval.t ......... ok   
2023-01-12 11:54:11,374 ERROR: t/35_next_method_in_anon.t ......... ok   
2023-01-12 11:54:11,374 ERROR: t/36_next_goto.t ................... ok   
2023-01-12 11:54:11,374 ERROR: t/37_mro_warn.t .................... skipped: MRO::Compat not available
2023-01-12 11:54:11,374 ERROR: t/pod.t ............................ skipped: Test::Pod 1.14 required for testing POD
2023-01-12 11:54:11,374 ERROR: t/pod_coverage.t ................... skipped: Test::Pod::Coverage 1.04 required for testing POD coverage
2023-01-12 11:54:11,374 ERROR: All tests successful.
2023-01-12 11:54:11,375 ERROR: Files=23, Tests=121,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.11 usr  0.03 sys +  1.13 cusr  0.29 csys =  1.56 CPU)
2023-01-12 11:54:11,375 ERROR: Result: PASS
2023-01-12 11:54:11,375 ERROR: installing
2023-01-12 11:54:11,375 ERROR: install flags: SHELL=/nix/store/wim4mqpn8lxhhr10p2kd070hyj152lil-bash-5.1-p16/bin/bash pkgconfigdir=/nix/store/siscvg80a7qqaihyqap35fm0gmry3fkz-perl5.36.0-Dancer2-0.400000/lib/pkgconfig m4datadir=/nix/store/siscvg80a7qqaihyqap35fm0gmry3fkz-perl5.36.0-Dancer2-0.400000/share/aclocal aclocaldir=/nix/store/siscvg80a7qqaihyqap35fm0gmry3fkz-perl5.36.0-Dancer2-0.400000/share/aclocal install
2023-01-12 11:54:11,375 ERROR: Manifying 2 pod documents
2023-01-12 11:54:11,375 ERROR: Installing /nix/store/siscvg80a7qqaihyqap35fm0gmry3fkz-perl5.36.0-Dancer2-0.400000/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.36.0/Class/C3.pm
2023-01-12 11:54:11,375 ERROR: Installing /nix/store/siscvg80a7qqaihyqap35fm0gmry3fkz-perl5.36.0-Dancer2-0.400000/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.36.0/Class/C3/next.pm
2023-01-12 11:54:11,375 ERROR: Installing /nix/store/siscvg80a7qqaihyqap35fm0gmry3fkz-perl5.36.0-Dancer2-0.400000/share/man/man3/Class::C3::next.3
2023-01-12 11:54:11,375 ERROR: Installing /nix/store/siscvg80a7qqaihyqap35fm0gmry3fkz-perl5.36.0-Dancer2-0.400000/share/man/man3/Class::C3.3
2023-01-12 11:54:11,375 ERROR: Appending installation info to /nix/store/siscvg80a7qqaihyqap35fm0gmry3fkz-perl5.36.0-Dancer2-0.400000/lib/perl5/5.36.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/perllocal.pod
2023-01-12 11:54:11,375 ERROR: post-installation fixup
2023-01-12 11:54:11,375 ERROR: Moving /nix/store/siscvg80a7qqaihyqap35fm0gmry3fkz-perl5.36.0-Dancer2-0.400000/share/man/man3 to /nix/store/jwvihi0i9igi3l8vif7ffm6i4k81fr49-perl5.36.0-Dancer2-0.400000-devdoc/share/man/man3
2023-01-12 11:54:11,375 ERROR: Removing empty /nix/store/siscvg80a7qqaihyqap35fm0gmry3fkz-perl5.36.0-Dancer2-0.400000/share/man/ and (possibly) its parents
2023-01-12 11:54:11,375 ERROR: shrinking RPATHs of ELF executables and libraries in /nix/store/siscvg80a7qqaihyqap35fm0gmry3fkz-perl5.36.0-Dancer2-0.400000
2023-01-12 11:54:11,375 ERROR: strip is /nix/store/a12yx0i0xh7i39bahq13jhmfplmn69ar-gcc-wrapper-11.3.0/bin/strip
2023-01-12 11:54:11,375 ERROR: stripping (with command strip and flags -S) in  /nix/store/siscvg80a7qqaihyqap35fm0gmry3fkz-perl5.36.0-Dancer2-0.400000/lib
2023-01-12 11:54:11,375 ERROR: patching script interpreter paths in /nix/store/siscvg80a7qqaihyqap35fm0gmry3fkz-perl5.36.0-Dancer2-0.400000
2023-01-12 11:54:11,375 ERROR: checking for references to /build/ in /nix/store/siscvg80a7qqaihyqap35fm0gmry3fkz-perl5.36.0-Dancer2-0.400000...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,375 ERROR: shrinking RPATHs of ELF executables and libraries in /nix/store/jwvihi0i9igi3l8vif7ffm6i4k81fr49-perl5.36.0-Dancer2-0.400000-devdoc
2023-01-12 11:54:11,375 ERROR: gzipping man pages under /nix/store/jwvihi0i9igi3l8vif7ffm6i4k81fr49-perl5.36.0-Dancer2-0.400000-devdoc/share/man/
2023-01-12 11:54:11,375 ERROR: strip is /nix/store/a12yx0i0xh7i39bahq13jhmfplmn69ar-gcc-wrapper-11.3.0/bin/strip
2023-01-12 11:54:11,375 ERROR: patching script interpreter paths in /nix/store/jwvihi0i9igi3l8vif7ffm6i4k81fr49-perl5.36.0-Dancer2-0.400000-devdoc
2023-01-12 11:54:11,375 ERROR: checking for references to /build/ in /nix/store/jwvihi0i9igi3l8vif7ffm6i4k81fr49-perl5.36.0-Dancer2-0.400000-devdoc...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,375 ERROR: building '/nix/store/x6d6q8y19pfb4zawfj937g69v4r68ip5-perl5.36.0-snapcast-volume-ui-0.21.drv'...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,375 ERROR: unpacking sources
2023-01-12 11:54:11,375 ERROR: unpacking source archive /nix/store/f9gz9j2f7cp540vi77y4ij4lp9hbwnm6-source
2023-01-12 11:54:11,375 ERROR: source root is source
2023-01-12 11:54:11,375 ERROR: patching sources
2023-01-12 11:54:11,375 ERROR: configuring
2023-01-12 11:54:11,375 ERROR: /nix/store/qf3mzpvsmkrw963xchbivcci06078n13-builder.sh: line 17: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
2023-01-12 11:54:11,375 ERROR: patching ./scripts/setVolume.py...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,375 ERROR: patching ./scripts/setVolume.pl...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,375 ERROR: patching ./scripts/mute.py...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,375 ERROR: patching ./scripts/getClients.py...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,375 ERROR: patching ./scripts/getClients.pl...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,375 ERROR: /nix/store/qf3mzpvsmkrw963xchbivcci06078n13-builder.sh: line 17: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
2023-01-12 11:54:11,375 ERROR: /nix/store/qf3mzpvsmkrw963xchbivcci06078n13-builder.sh: line 17: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
2023-01-12 11:54:11,376 ERROR: patching ./public/dispatch.fcgi...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,376 ERROR: patching ./public/dispatch.cgi...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,376 ERROR: patching ./bin/app.psgi...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,376 ERROR: patching ./production-server...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,376 ERROR: patching ./install.sh...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,376 ERROR: patching ./devel-server...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,376 ERROR: Checking if your kit is complete...
2023-01-12 11:54:11,376 ERROR: Warning: the following files are missing in your kit:
2023-01-12 11:54:11,376 ERROR:         .dancer
2023-01-12 11:54:11,376 ERROR:         config.yml
2023-01-12 11:54:11,376 ERROR:         public/css/style.css
2023-01-12 11:54:11,376 ERROR: Please inform the author.
2023-01-12 11:54:11,376 ERROR: Warning: prerequisite Dancer2 0.166001 not found.
2023-01-12 11:54:11,376 ERROR: Warning: prerequisite YAML 0 not found.
2023-01-12 11:54:11,376 ERROR: Generating a Unix-style Makefile
2023-01-12 11:54:11,376 ERROR: Writing Makefile for snapdance
2023-01-12 11:54:11,376 ERROR: Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
2023-01-12 11:54:11,376 ERROR: no configure script, doing nothing
2023-01-12 11:54:11,376 ERROR: building
2023-01-12 11:54:11,376 ERROR: build flags: SHELL=/nix/store/wim4mqpn8lxhhr10p2kd070hyj152lil-bash-5.1-p16/bin/bash
2023-01-12 11:54:11,376 ERROR: cp lib/snapdance.pm blib/lib/snapdance.pm
2023-01-12 11:54:11,376 ERROR: running tests
2023-01-12 11:54:11,376 ERROR: check flags: SHELL=/nix/store/wim4mqpn8lxhhr10p2kd070hyj152lil-bash-5.1-p16/bin/bash VERBOSE=y test
2023-01-12 11:54:11,376 ERROR: PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/nix/store/ir8rqkxsqh0ar3avlvhs2crn0zx2d2mk-perl-5.36.0/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
2023-01-12 11:54:11,376 ERROR: t/001_base.t ......... 1/1 
2023-01-12 11:54:11,376 ERROR: #   Failed test 'use snapdance;'
2023-01-12 11:54:11,376 ERROR: #   at t/001_base.t line 5.
2023-01-12 11:54:11,376 ERROR: #     Tried to use 'snapdance'.
2023-01-12 11:54:11,376 ERROR: #     Error:  Can't locate Dancer2.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Dancer2 module) (@INC contains: /build/source/blib/lib /build/source/blib/arch /nix/store/ir8rqkxsqh0ar3avlvhs2crn0zx2d2mk-perl-5.36.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.36.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /nix/store/ir8rqkxsqh0ar3avlvhs2crn0zx2d2mk-perl-5.36.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.36.0 /nix/store/ir8rqkxsqh0ar3avlvhs2crn0zx2d2mk-perl-5.36.0/lib/perl5/site_perl /nix/store/siscvg80a7qqaihyqap35fm0gmry3fkz-perl5.36.0-Dancer2-0.400000/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.36.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /nix/store/siscvg80a7qqaihyqap35fm0gmry3fkz-perl5.36.0-Dancer2-0.400000/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.36.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /nix/store/siscvg80a7qqaihyqap35fm0gmry3fkz-perl5.36.0-Dancer2-0.400000/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.36.0 /nix/store/siscvg80a7qqaihyqap35fm0gmry3fkz-perl5.36.0-Dancer2-0.400000/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.36.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /nix/store/siscvg80a7qqaihyqap35fm0gmry3fkz-perl5.36.0-Dancer2-0.400000/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.36.0 /nix/store/siscvg80a7qqaihyqap35fm0gmry3fkz-perl5.36.0-Dancer2-0.400000/lib/perl5/site_perl /nix/store/18p7z804r07i0yivdq0ihjvj2499kmxz-perl5.36.0-snapcast-volume-ui-0.21/lib/perl5/site_perl /nix/store/ir8rqkxsqh0ar3avlvhs2crn0zx2d2mk-perl-5.36.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.36.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /nix/store/ir8rqkxsqh0ar3avlvhs2crn0zx2d2mk-perl-5.36.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.36.0 /nix/store/ir8rqkxsqh0ar3avlvhs2crn0zx2d2mk-perl-5.36.0/lib/perl5/site_perl /nix/store/siscvg80a7qqaihyqap35fm0gmry3fkz-perl5.36.0-Dancer2-0.400000/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.36.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /nix/store/siscvg80a7qqaihyqap35fm0gmry3fkz-perl5.36.0-Dancer2-0.400000/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.36.0 /nix/store/siscvg80a7qqaihyqap35fm0gmry3fkz-perl5.36.0-Dancer2-0.400000/lib/perl5/site_perl /nix/store/18p7z804r07i0yivdq0ihjvj2499kmxz-perl5.36.0-snapcast-volume-ui-0.21/lib/perl5/site_perl /nix/store/ir8rqkxsqh0ar3avlvhs2crn0zx2d2mk-perl-5.36.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.36.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /nix/store/ir8rqkxsqh0ar3avlvhs2crn0zx2d2mk-perl-5.36.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.36.0 /nix/store/ir8rqkxsqh0ar3avlvhs2crn0zx2d2mk-perl-5.36.0/lib/perl5/5.36.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /nix/store/ir8rqkxsqh0ar3avlvhs2crn0zx2d2mk-perl-5.36.0/lib/perl5/5.36.0 .) at /build/source/blib/lib/snapdance.pm line 2.
2023-01-12 11:54:11,376 ERROR: # BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /build/source/blib/lib/snapdance.pm line 2.
2023-01-12 11:54:11,376 ERROR: # Compilation failed in require at t/001_base.t line 5.
2023-01-12 11:54:11,376 ERROR: # BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/001_base.t line 5.
2023-01-12 11:54:11,376 ERROR: # Looks like you failed 1 test of 1.
2023-01-12 11:54:11,376 ERROR: t/001_base.t ......... Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
2023-01-12 11:54:11,376 ERROR: Failed 1/1 subtests 
2023-01-12 11:54:11,376 ERROR: t/002_index_route.t .. Can't locate Dancer2.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Dancer2 module) (@INC contains: /build/source/blib/lib /build/source/blib/arch /nix/store/ir8rqkxsqh0ar3avlvhs2crn0zx2d2mk-perl-5.36.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.36.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /nix/store/ir8rqkxsqh0ar3avlvhs2crn0zx2d2mk-perl-5.36.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.36.0 /nix/store/ir8rqkxsqh0ar3avlvhs2crn0zx2d2mk-perl-5.36.0/lib/perl5/site_perl /nix/store/siscvg80a7qqaihyqap35fm0gmry3fkz-perl5.36.0-Dancer2-0.400000/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.36.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /nix/store/siscvg80a7qqaihyqap35fm0gmry3fkz-perl5.36.0-Dancer2-0.400000/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.36.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /nix/store/siscvg80a7qqaihyqap35fm0gmry3fkz-perl5.36.0-Dancer2-0.400000/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.36.0 /nix/store/siscvg80a7qqaihyqap35fm0gmry3fkz-perl5.36.0-Dancer2-0.400000/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.36.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /nix/store/siscvg80a7qqaihyqap35fm0gmry3fkz-perl5.36.0-Dancer2-0.400000/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.36.0 /nix/store/siscvg80a7qqaihyqap35fm0gmry3fkz-perl5.36.0-Dancer2-0.400000/lib/perl5/site_perl /nix/store/18p7z804r07i0yivdq0ihjvj2499kmxz-perl5.36.0-snapcast-volume-ui-0.21/lib/perl5/site_perl /nix/store/ir8rqkxsqh0ar3avlvhs2crn0zx2d2mk-perl-5.36.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.36.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /nix/store/ir8rqkxsqh0ar3avlvhs2crn0zx2d2mk-perl-5.36.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.36.0 /nix/store/ir8rqkxsqh0ar3avlvhs2crn0zx2d2mk-perl-5.36.0/lib/perl5/site_perl /nix/store/siscvg80a7qqaihyqap35fm0gmry3fkz-perl5.36.0-Dancer2-0.400000/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.36.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /nix/store/siscvg80a7qqaihyqap35fm0gmry3fkz-perl5.36.0-Dancer2-0.400000/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.36.0 /nix/store/siscvg80a7qqaihyqap35fm0gmry3fkz-perl5.36.0-Dancer2-0.400000/lib/perl5/site_perl /nix/store/18p7z804r07i0yivdq0ihjvj2499kmxz-perl5.36.0-snapcast-volume-ui-0.21/lib/perl5/site_perl /nix/store/ir8rqkxsqh0ar3avlvhs2crn0zx2d2mk-perl-5.36.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.36.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /nix/store/ir8rqkxsqh0ar3avlvhs2crn0zx2d2mk-perl-5.36.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.36.0 /nix/store/ir8rqkxsqh0ar3avlvhs2crn0zx2d2mk-perl-5.36.0/lib/perl5/5.36.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /nix/store/ir8rqkxsqh0ar3avlvhs2crn0zx2d2mk-perl-5.36.0/lib/perl5/5.36.0 .) at /build/source/blib/lib/snapdance.pm line 2.
2023-01-12 11:54:11,377 ERROR: BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /build/source/blib/lib/snapdance.pm line 2.
2023-01-12 11:54:11,377 ERROR: Compilation failed in require at t/002_index_route.t line 4.
2023-01-12 11:54:11,377 ERROR: BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/002_index_route.t line 4.
2023-01-12 11:54:11,377 ERROR: t/002_index_route.t .. Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
2023-01-12 11:54:11,377 ERROR: No subtests run 
2023-01-12 11:54:11,377 ERROR: 
2023-01-12 11:54:11,377 ERROR: Test Summary Report
2023-01-12 11:54:11,377 ERROR: -------------------
2023-01-12 11:54:11,377 ERROR: t/001_base.t       (Wstat: 256 (exited 1) Tests: 1 Failed: 1)
2023-01-12 11:54:11,377 ERROR:   Failed test:  1
2023-01-12 11:54:11,377 ERROR:   Non-zero exit status: 1
2023-01-12 11:54:11,377 ERROR: t/002_index_route.t (Wstat: 512 (exited 2) Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
2023-01-12 11:54:11,377 ERROR:   Non-zero exit status: 2
2023-01-12 11:54:11,377 ERROR:   Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
2023-01-12 11:54:11,377 ERROR: Files=2, Tests=1,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.02 usr  0.01 sys +  0.05 cusr  0.01 csys =  0.09 CPU)
2023-01-12 11:54:11,377 ERROR: Result: FAIL
2023-01-12 11:54:11,377 ERROR: Failed 2/2 test programs. 1/1 subtests failed.
2023-01-12 11:54:11,377 ERROR: make: *** [Makefile:851: test_dynamic] Error 2
2023-01-12 11:54:11,377 ERROR: error: builder for '/nix/store/x6d6q8y19pfb4zawfj937g69v4r68ip5-perl5.36.0-snapcast-volume-ui-0.21.drv' failed with exit code 2;
2023-01-12 11:54:11,377 ERROR:        last 10 log lines:
2023-01-12 11:54:11,377 ERROR:        > t/001_base.t       (Wstat: 256 (exited 1) Tests: 1 Failed: 1)
2023-01-12 11:54:11,377 ERROR:        >   Failed test:  1
2023-01-12 11:54:11,377 ERROR:        >   Non-zero exit status: 1
2023-01-12 11:54:11,377 ERROR:        > t/002_index_route.t (Wstat: 512 (exited 2) Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
2023-01-12 11:54:11,377 ERROR:        >   Non-zero exit status: 2
2023-01-12 11:54:11,377 ERROR:        >   Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
2023-01-12 11:54:11,377 ERROR:        > Files=2, Tests=1,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.02 usr  0.01 sys +  0.05 cusr  0.01 csys =  0.09 CPU)
2023-01-12 11:54:11,377 ERROR:        > Result: FAIL
2023-01-12 11:54:11,377 ERROR:        > Failed 2/2 test programs. 1/1 subtests failed.
2023-01-12 11:54:11,377 ERROR:        > make: *** [Makefile:851: test_dynamic] Error 2
2023-01-12 11:54:11,377 ERROR:        For full logs, run 'nix log /nix/store/x6d6q8y19pfb4zawfj937g69v4r68ip5-perl5.36.0-snapcast-volume-ui-0.21.drv'.
2023-01-12 11:54:11,377 ERROR: error: 1 dependencies of derivation '/nix/store/lf2vzi293xsxa5ajcqhclgkcmanmr9rb-snapcast-volume-ui-customisation-layer.drv' failed to build
2023-01-12 11:54:11,377 ERROR: error: 1 dependencies of derivation '/nix/store/jyggj3jjjw46wsynn7lvsk59013xn700-snapcast-volume-ui-conf.json.drv' failed to build
2023-01-12 11:54:11,377 ERROR: error: 1 dependencies of derivation '/nix/store/mcygch1j39765w9znmxlmyly44nwcvnw-stream-snapcast-volume-ui.drv' failed to build
2023-01-12 11:54:11,377 ERROR: error: 1 dependencies of derivation '/nix/store/v6ah4zaj3vckiw7mwmsszim3iz9isjcj-snapcast-volume-ui.tar.gz.drv' failed to build
2023-01-12 11:54:11,377 ERROR: error: 1 dependencies of derivation '/nix/store/b24jqp3zny42r4v5w3asvrkzagrvhaga-images.ini.drv' failed to build
2023-01-12 11:54:11,377 ERROR:
```

Why is the build failing to find the Dancer2 dependency, even though it's added as a `propagatedBuildInputs`?

For context, I'm building it using a `services.nix`:

```
let
  config = import ./config.nix;
  pkgs = config.pkgs;
  snapcast-volume-ui = import ./services/snapcast-volume-ui.nix;
in rec {
  serviceimages = pkgs.writeText "images.ini" ''
    [containers]
    snapcast-volume-ui=${snapcast-volume-ui(pkgs)}
  '';
}
```

and my `config.nix` just has the current nix 22.11 package tree:

```
{
  # nixos-22.11
  pkgs = import (fetchTarball "https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/2343b4753e1e17e3a9ee21ac4b4b178a98fe82ae.tar.gz") {};
}
```

Comment: "How do I package software X?" is on the same scale as "how do I write a homework program that does X?" -- the title is not limited to the one problem you encountered and are asking about but incorporates anything else that comes up after that problem is solved. Please try not to do that -- it's a lot less commitment to agree to answer the narrow, specific problem (in this case the specific dependency not being found) without any agreement to look into that one issue implying agreement to solve any other problems that come up while packaging the same software.

Comment: BTW, not asserting that this is the problem (hence adding a comment rather than an answer as I might after testing the fix), but I  do note that there's dependency on a very specific version of Dancer2 (`0.166001`, whereas you're packaging `0.400000`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm asking a very specific packaging questions, about a very specific packaging system, with 100% of the code and the error message. If you gripe is the title, I can change it to "Issues with dependencies for building snapcast-volume-ui in Nix," but comparing this to a homework problem is just rude and uncalled for.

Comment: Yes, it's indeed only the title I was griping about. "nixpkgs buildPerlPackage not recognizing dependency provided via propagatedBuildInputs" is how I'd write it; that way the title is narrowly focused on what the issue _is_. BTW, did you manage to check whether using the explicitly-requested version of Dancer2 fixes the problem?

Comment: The issue was not with the version. I was using the wrong hash and it was pulling the wrong perl package to start with, but then I found issues with several missing CPAN dependencies and there was a lot involved with correctly wrapping everything. I posted a fully working solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a lot involved in getting this to work in a nix container. There were several additional CPAN packages I needed to build and wrap together. The following is the full result:

```
{ pkgs, lib, fetchurl, ... }:
let
snapcast-volume-ui-config = pkgs.writeTextFile {
    name = "snapcast-volume-ui-config";
    destination = "/snap-cast-volume-ui/config.yml";
    text = ''
    appname: "snapdance"
    layout: "main"
    template: "template_toolkit"
    engines:
      template:
        template_toolkit:
          start_tag: '<%'
          end_tag:   '%>'
    snapcast:
      demo: 0
      server:
         host: 'natalie'
         port: 1705
      rooms:
        'ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee':
           color: '#0C0'
           name:  'Mezzanine'
    '';
};

TestLib = pkgs.perlPackages.buildPerlPackage {
  pname = "Test-Lib";
  version = "0.003";
  src = fetchurl {
    url = "mirror://cpan/authors/id/H/HA/HAARG/Test-Lib-0.003.tar.gz";
    sha256 = "d84b48d92567cba3d0afb1e8175aab836bfa8a838e19ac9080cabc2e3f9dc9f5";
  };
  meta = {
    description = "Use libraries from a t/lib directory";
    license = with lib.licenses; [ artistic1 gpl1Plus ];
  };
};


CLIOsprey = pkgs.perlPackages.buildPerlModule rec {
  pname = "CLI-Osprey";
  version = "0.08";
  src = fetchurl {
    url = "mirror://cpan/authors/id/A/AR/ARODLAND/CLI-Osprey-0.08.tar.gz";
    sha256 = "f7480523dbdf2c2b53789c06a8bd91cf6579bb8cc5678e72ea8a1faaab30d19a";
  };
  buildInputs = [
    pkgs.perlPackages.CaptureTiny
    pkgs.perlPackages.ModuleBuildTiny
    TestLib
  ];
  propagatedBuildInputs = [
    pkgs.perlPackages.GetoptLongDescriptive
    pkgs.perlPackages.ModuleRuntime
    pkgs.perlPackages.Moo
    pkgs.perlPackages.PathTiny
  ];
  meta = {
    homepage = "http://metacpan.org/release/CLI-Osprey";
    description = "MooX::Options + MooX::Cmd + Sanity";
    license = with lib.licenses; [ artistic1 gpl1Plus ];
  };
};

Dancer2 = pkgs.perlPackages.buildPerlPackage rec {
  pname = "Dancer2";
  version = "0.400000";
  src = fetchurl {
    url = "mirror://cpan/authors/id/C/CR/CROMEDOME/${pname}-${version}.tar.gz";
    sha256 = "e6cf7a5eed29261087d2ce6db631d28b4e870cb14f31c2dfa2f77c0163bc435c";
  };
  buildInputs = [
    pkgs.perlPackages.CaptureTiny
    pkgs.perlPackages.FileShareDirInstall
    pkgs.perlPackages.HTTPCookies
    pkgs.perlPackages.HTTPMessage
    pkgs.perlPackages.TestEOL
    pkgs.perlPackages.TestFatal
  ];
  propagatedBuildInputs = [
    CLIOsprey
    pkgs.perlPackages.Clone
    pkgs.perlPackages.ConfigAny
    pkgs.perlPackages.ExporterTiny
    pkgs.perlPackages.FileShare
    pkgs.perlPackages.FileWhich
    pkgs.perlPackages.HTTPDate
    pkgs.perlPackages.HTTPHeadersFast
    pkgs.perlPackages.HashMergeSimple
    pkgs.perlPackages.HashMultiValue
    pkgs.perlPackages.ImportInto
    pkgs.perlPackages.JSONMaybeXS
    pkgs.perlPackages.ModuleRuntime
    pkgs.perlPackages.Moo
    pkgs.perlPackages.PathTiny
    pkgs.perlPackages.Plack
    pkgs.perlPackages.PlackMiddlewareFixMissingBodyInRedirect
    pkgs.perlPackages.PlackMiddlewareRemoveRedundantBody
    pkgs.perlPackages.RefUtil
    pkgs.perlPackages.RoleTiny
    pkgs.perlPackages.SafeIsa
    pkgs.perlPackages.SubQuote
    pkgs.perlPackages.TemplateTiny
    pkgs.perlPackages.TemplateToolkit
    pkgs.perlPackages.TypeTiny
    pkgs.perlPackages.URI
    pkgs.perlPackages.YAML
  ];
  meta = {
    homepage = "http://perldancer.org/";
    description = "Lightweight yet powerful web application framework";
    license = with lib.licenses; [ artistic1 gpl1Plus ];
  };
};

snapcast-volume-ui-src = fetchGit {
  url = "https://github.com/atoomic/snapcast-volume-ui.git";
  ref = "snapcast/v0.12";
  rev = "5eb4076607aab7e69b08a96b902029bd1091c056";
};

snapcast-volume-ui-dir = pkgs.runCommand "" {
  paths = [ snapcast-volume-ui-src ];
} ''
  mkdir -p $out/snap-cast-volume-ui
  cp -r ${snapcast-volume-ui-src}/* $out/snap-cast-volume-ui
  '';

SimpleAccessor = pkgs.perlPackages.buildPerlPackage {
  pname = "Simple-Accessor";
  version = "1.13";
  src = fetchurl {
    url = "mirror://cpan/authors/id/A/AT/ATOOMIC/Simple-Accessor-1.13.tar.gz";
    sha256 = "5af6066c7a9f58ab963e36d12052bcc5b20e80ee32f3899ea882a79192882226";
  };
  meta = {
    description = "A light and simple way to provide accessor in perl";
    license = with lib.licenses; [ artistic1 gpl1Plus ];
  };
};

perl = pkgs.perl536;
perl-with-packages = perl.withPackages (p: with p; [
    pkgs.perlPackages.TestMoreUTF8
    pkgs.perlPackages.HTTPMessage
    pkgs.perlPackages.TestSimple13
    pkgs.perlPackages.JSONXS
    pkgs.perlPackages.NetTelnet
    pkgs.perlPackages.HTTPParserXS
    SimpleAccessor
    Dancer2
]);

in
pkgs.dockerTools.buildLayeredImage {
  name = "snapcast-volume-ui";
  contents = [ pkgs.busybox snapcast-volume-ui-dir snapcast-volume-ui-config perl-with-packages
              ];
  config = {
    Entrypoint = [ "plackup" "-p" "1705" "-R" "/snap-cast-volume-ui" "snap-cast-volume-ui/bin/app.psgi" ];
    Env = [];
    Volumes = {};
  };
}
```